# ¿Que hace este código?

Tags: python, python-3.x

soy nuevo en Python y no he logrado entender que función tiene este código:

```
t = int(input())
cont = 1
while(cont <= t):
    salida = ""
    n,x,y = input().split()
    cont_i=1
    while(cont_i < int(n)):
        if(cont_i % int(x) == 0 and cont_i % int(y) != 0):
            salida = salida + str(cont_i) + " "
        cont_i += 1
    print(salida)
    cont += 1
```

Muchas gracias :)

Comment: te pone los numeros 1 al n de forma ascendente en una cadena y los va imprimiendo

Comment: Pero no entiendo porqué al ejecutarlo me pide un número, lo pongo y luego me pide otro, y cuando lo pongo sale:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Jordan.py", line 5, in <module>
    n,x,y = input().split()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

Comment: El error ocurre porque la función `split()` solo puedes aplicarlo a un **string**, y en el caso que planteas esta de mas, lo correcto es `n,x,y = input()`, esto solicitara 3 valores numéricos a cargar en n,x,y.

Comment: Como comento en mi respuesta lo que espera que le ingreses son tres numeros separados por un espacio, por ejemplo: `20 2 3`. Esa es la razón del `split()`, si le pasas solo un número (o cualquier cosa con menos de 2 espacios) da el error porque `split` retorna una lista de un elemento cuando hay tres a desempaquetar (`n,x,y` )

Answer (score 1):

Es difícil saber el uso que se le da a esto sin un contexto, no obstante lo que hace básicamente es dados 3 números `n`, `x` e `y` **imprimir aquellos números que son divisibles por `x` pero que no lo son también por `y` en el rango comprendido entre 1 y `n`-1**:

Es decir, para:

```
n = 20
x = 2
y = 3
```

Nos imprime todos los número divisbles entre 2 pero que no son divisbles entre 3 también (como el 6 o el 12) comprendidos entre 1 y 19. La salida sería algo como:

> 2 4 8 10 14 16

Estos numeros son introducidos como una cadena única separadados por espacios:

> 20 2 3

Son separados por el método split retornado una lista de la forma `["20", "2" ,"3"]`.

Posteriormente solo se calcula los numeros comprendidos entre 1 y `n`-1 usando un while y un contador y se mira si son divibles por `x` y no por `y` usando el resto de la división mediante el operador módulo (`%`). Si cumple la condicón se agregan a una cadena para ser imprimidos al concluir el ciclo.

Esto lo hace para `t` veces, con el primer `input` damos las veces que queremos introducir los tres números y que imprima lo explicado antes. El código es no obstante bastante ineficiente y poco apropiado para el zen de Python, para hacer esto de forma más apropiada sin usar cosar demasiado 'raras':

```
t = int(input('Ingrese el total de entradas: '))
for _ in range(t):
    n,x,y = (int(i) for i in input('Ingrese n, x e y separados por un espacio: ').split())
    for i in range(n):
        if not (i % x) and (i % y):
            print(i, end = ' ')
    print()
```

Un ejemplo de uso y sus salidas:

> Ingrese el total de entradas: 2
>   Ingrese n, x e y separados por un espacio: 20 2 3
>   2 4 8 10 14 16
>   Ingrese n, x e y separados por un espacio: 40 3 7
>   3 6 9 12 15 18 24 27 30 33 36 39